# Codeigniter and Opauth twitter strategy User denied access

Tags: codeigniter, api, twitter

I'm trying to implement login through twitter using Opauth on Codeigniter, it work fine in localhost but when i website goes live, i get this error:

```
Array (
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => access_denied
            [message] => User denied access.
            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [oauth_token] => XXXXXXXXX
                    [oauth_verifier] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
                )
            [provider] => Twitter
        )
    [timestamp] => 2015-10-09T14:18:58+00:00 )
```

I accept the connection, i didn't deny it. i change the website and callback api to be my domain. but i get the above error . when i test it on localhost (website: localhost + callback: localhost) it work fine i dont get any error . i dont know why it work on local host and it doesn't wok on live

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the problem was htacces. so i use this code and it works now

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```